# How do I Parse and Display Json data using c# on xamarin android?

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I am trying to pull Json data using c# and display it using xamarin android. I have tried code like this to send the request

```
private async Task<JsonValue> GetTeams(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers["X-Auth-Token"] = key;

            using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
                    JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());

                    // Return the JSON document:
                    return jsonDoc;
                }
            }
        }
```

and the following to parse and display

```
private void ParseAndDisplay(JsonValue json)
        {
            dynamic teamData = json["teams"];

            TextView name = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);

            foreach (var team in teamData)
            {
                //name.Text = team["name"];
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n {0}", team["name"]);
            }
        }
```

Nothing displays on my phone when run but I can see all the data in the output. 
A link to the output is http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/teams

Comment: use newtonsoft.json

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta I have that declared but it is never used? I am using system.json but I am never prompted to use newtonsoft.json

Comment: you have to actually use the Newtonsoft class in code - their website has numerous examples.

Comment: Ok I will look there. Does that mean the code I have here is useless to me now?

Comment: you only have 1 line that is actually doing the JSON deserialization - you will have to replace that